# How to run apk file on Mac via Bluestacks

Tags: android, macos, apk, bluestacks

I use Bluestacks as a Virtual device to run apk file on my laptop. On Windows, it is quite simple. I just need to install Bluestacks, then double click to the apk file I want to run. It will automatically install to Bluestacks. However, it is a pain on Mac. After installed Bluestacks, I still can not open apk file.

Anybody know how to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Double click for installing, It works well on mac too.

Answer (score 11):

Just right click work for me.
Mac 10.12.1

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Open terminal and run the following command:

```
~/Library/BlueStacks\ App\ Player/Runtime/uHD-Adb install PATH_AND_APK_FILENAME
```

Comment: If you get an error `adb server is out of date.  killing...
cannot bind 'tcp:5037'
ADB server didn't ACK
* failed to start daemon *
error:` you have to run `~/Library/BlueStacks\ App\ Player/Runtime/uHD-Adb devices` first.

Answer (score 6):

This is for Bluestack Version 0.9.30.

Just right click the `.apk` file and `Open With` like:
[image]

look for `BlueStacks.app` and wait for the installation to finish.

**Note**: If the `default` app is already BlueStacks you can just double click the .apk file.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use [Genymotion](http://genymotion.com/), its fast and supports many features which blue stacks don't, its easy to install too.

Answer (score 0):

Download Astro File Manager, Open, find your file from sdcards(SD Cards are your mac hard drive), press apk file, install, and complete!

Comment: It would be nice if you add a link to _Astro File Manager_ ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Unplug all your physical Android devices, turn off other virtual devices and open terminal, type this:

adb install -r PATH TO APK.apk

like this:

[image]